# Currently looking at spaces for a number of home brew kits. Looking for guidance in any way

Tags: equipment, brewing

I am currently trying to organize a space for a collective of 10 brewers to store their 2-5 gallon kits. I'm currently looking into studios, as the area that I am in does not have many options for garages or storage container workshops.

We are only beginning and therefore what are the most basic essentials to get us going?

And how should we best organize a small space for small scale home brewing?

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with homebrewing. Sounds like you should be on Craislist looking for a rental space.

Comment: Are you looking to buy equipment or just need to know how to organize the space?

Answer (score 2):

The basic requirements for the space should have:

1. Running water
2. a good sink with a good drain
3. Oven and stove
4. Electricity to support however many burners you’ll use at the same
   time.
5. A Restroom

Then you’ll want lots of shelves for buckets, carboys and conical fermenters. Bakers rack can work for this but place a 1/4 sheet of ply wood on the shelves to protect the carboys and buckets.

Make sure you create enough space to walk comfortably (not shuffling) between shelves or you’ll regret it.

Answer (score 1):

Use Bakers racks, those metal wire shelves you see in restaurants, you can buy at most general merchandise stores (e.g. Walmart, Meijer)

you can store 3-4x 6 gallon bucket fermentors. I use one that stores all my equipment including my burner, imersion cooler, and about 6 buckets. and dont forget to get your rubbermade totes to store the small stuff.....

Basic stuff you will need, is a burner or someway to heat water and boil wort.
immersion cooler or other way to cool wort. bottling or kegging equipment.

I could go on with all the equipment that could be needed. but you will have to see what people have or willing to donate...etc.

Hope this answers your question.